# Side navigation bar to be displayed on right side using angular material?

Tags: html, css, angular6, typescript-typings, angular-material-6

Side navigation to be dispalyed on the right side using angular material?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby

Result is side nave to be displayed on right side

Answer (score 4):

Add `position="end"` on `mat-sidenav`

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav position="end" class="example-sidenav" mode="side" opened="true">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-jthbio?file=app/sidenav-autosize-example.html